# YAML parsing in Google Dart?

Tags: yaml, dart

I do not see any mention of YAML parsing capabilities anywhere in the docs. I can't also find any YAML parser libraries in the Internet, then I found this:

http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/utils/pub/yaml/?r=7264

I guess I either make one myself or I copy the code from that repository -- or is there some way to use the package manager to install that YAML library?

Clearly that is a working YAML parser library:

```
library yaml;
```

How would I install this library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
import '/Users/alex/my/src/dart/dart/utils/pub/yaml/yaml.dart';
```

whereby "/Users/alex/my/src/dart" is my local Dart repository clone.

Comment: I added a bug asking to make that part of the standard library: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4126&thanks=4126&ts=1342543979

Answer (score 3):

It has now been added as pub repository: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/yaml